# Using rake import (calling other rakefiles)

Tags: ruby, import, rake, rakefile

Here's my primary rake file

```
subrake = 'subrake'

task :init => [subrake] do
  #call subrake.build
end

import subrake
```

I see documentation on how the above steps work, but I can't figure out how to call tasks in the other subrake file.  BTW, those tasks may have the same name as mine, is this an issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess I'm late with my answer, but I had the same question just few moments ago. So the solution might be useful for someone.

*Rakefile.rb*

```
subrake = 'subrake'

task :default => :init

task :init => ["#{subrake}:init"] do
  Rake::Task["#{subrake}:build"].invoke
end

require "#{Dir.pwd}/#{subrake}"
```

*subrake.rb*

```
namespace :subrake do

  desc "Init"
  task :init do
    puts 'Init called'
  end

  desc "Build"
  task :build do
    puts 'Build called'
  end

end
```

I guess the code describes itself just good, but I want to stop on one moment. When you are calling **require**, you should provide for a *subrake* file a full path (like in my sample) or '.\subrake' (if it is in a working directory)

Answer (score 5):

If you have more than one sub rake files you could do something like

```
Dir.glob('**/*.rake').each { |r| import r}

task :init => ["subrake:init"]
```

and you can have a sub.rake files that looks like so

```
namespace :subrake do
  desc "Init"
  task :init do
    puts 'Init called'
  end
end
```

and another foo.rake file

```
namespace :foorake do
  desc "Init"
  task :init do
    puts 'Init called'
  end
end
```

and you can call foorake:init from the shell like so

```
#rake foorake:init
```

or add it to you main do task like so

```
task :init => ["subrake:init", "fforake:init"]
```

Comment: I like this answer because it feels closer to how Minitest and RSpec work, and searching for certain types of files.