# How to require a Ruby file from another directory

Tags: ruby, require

I want to `require` a Ruby file in another file. These two files are in two different directories. I have `require second_file` at the top of the first file. Ruby says it can't load such file. Is that because it's in a different directory? I tried writing the full path to the second file but it still can't load the file.

How can I load the second file into the first?

Answer (score 74):

`require` will search for files in only a set of locations referred to as the "Load Path." You can view the load path by using the global variable `$LOAD_PATH` in a script or irb session. If it is not in the load path, it won't find it.

Ruby 1.9 introduced `require_relative` which searches using the current file's location as a starting point.

```
# Will search $LOAD_PATH for file. 
require 'test/unit'
# Notice the '/' which tells it to look in the 
# 'test' folder for a file named 'unit.rb'

# Will look in current folder of file
require_relative 'my_folder/my_file'
# Will search in 'my_folder' for the file 'my_file.rb'
```

Note that `require_relative` will not work in irb.

Also note, that if you really want to use `require`, you can start your script by adding a location to the `$LOAD_PATH` variable.

```
$LOAD_PATH << File.join('users', 'yourusername', 'your_folder')
# or
$LOAD_PATH << File.dirname(__FILE__)
# The second one enables you to move the file around on your
# system and still operate correctly
require 'my_file'
```

Here's some additional documentation from Ruby-Doc:

- [`$LOAD_PATH`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/globals_rdoc.html)
- [`require`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require)
- [`require_relative`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative)
- [`File.dirname`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/File.html#method-c-dirname)
- [`__FILE__`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-__FILE__)

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, but just one question what goes inside the brackets?
Is it the name of user, the username and the filepath to the folder

Comment: That was just an example. I used that as an example Linux's home directory. It could just as easily be `File.join('C:', 'Users', 'Charles', 'blahblah')` or even `File.dirname(__FILE__)` which will add the folder of where your current file is located to the load path. `dirname` is probably better since it will enable you to move the file around and still work.

Comment: Does your Rake file end in '.rb' or '.rake'? `require` only looks for '.rb'. If it ends in '.rake' then you might consider looking at [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4505996/using-rake-import-calling-other-rakefiles) which talks about using `import`.

Comment: You're welcome. There's a [blog by Glenn Gentzke](http://blog.smartlogicsolutions.com/2009/05/26/including-external-rake-files-in-your-projects-rakefile-keep-your-rake-tasks-organized/) that mentions basically the exact same thing the SO question does. Interesting conundrum.

Comment: Probably stupid question but i'm getting undefined method 'import' error when I try to import .rake file. Would you know of an answer to it?
Do I need to include something?

Comment: FYI, to see what is all included in your `LOAD_PATH` for your current environment, run `puts $LOAD_PATH` in the Rails console.

Answer (score 13):

Also possible to do so:

```
require './something.rb'
```

from current directory to include.

Answer (score 11):

From the docs: It suggests to use require relative. [**Docs**](http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html)

`require_relative` complements the builtin method require by allowing you to load a file that is relative to the file containing the `require_relative` statement.

When you use `require` to load a file, you are usually accessing functionality that has been properly installed, and made accessible, in your system. require does not offer a good solution for loading files within the project’s code. This may be useful during a development phase, for accessing test data, or even for accessing files that are "locked" away inside a project, not intended for outside use.

For example, if you have unit test classes in the "test" directory, and data for them under the test "test/data" directory, then you might use a line like this in a test case:

```
require_relative "data/customer_data_1"
```

Answer (score 3):

For example, you have files:

chess.rb and spec/test.rb

And you want to require the file in spec/test.rb. Use:

```
require_relative '../test.rb'
```

with two dots. With one dot './' you will have an error "cannot load such file"

Comment: Or require_relative '../test'