# ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1) for 'initialize'?

Tags: ruby, minitest, log4r

Fairly new to ruby, playing with Mini Test and log4r, trying to write a wrapper class.

Getting the following error:

```
$ ruby logger.rb
Run options: --seed 4605

# Running tests:

E

Finished tests in 0.000000s, Inf tests/s, NaN assertions/s.

  1) Error:
test_debug_messages(TestLogger):
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
    /home/jamlopez/scripts/Yatra.Next/rpm_framework/lib/rpm/core/logger.rb:5:in `initialize'
    logger.rb:6:in `new'
    logger.rb:6:in `setup'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Here's the class:

```
class RPMLogger
    def initialize
        require 'log4r', :version=>'=1.1.10'
        @log = Logger.new 'log'
        @log.outputters = Outputter.stdout
        @logfile_location = brpm_home
        @timenow = eval( Time.now.utc.iso8601 )
    end
    def debug( msg )
        @log.debug ( '[DEBUG] ' + @timenow + " #{msg}" )
    end
    def info( msg )
        @log.info ( '[INFO] ' + @timenow + " #{msg}" )
    end
    def warn( msg )
        @log.warn ( '[WARNING] ' + @timenow + " #{msg}" )
    end
    def error( msg )
        @log.error ( '[ERROR] ' + @timenow + " #{msg}" )
    end
    def fatal( msg )
        @log.fatal ( '[FATAL] ' + @timenow + " #{msg}" )
    end
end
```

And here's the test:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
require_relative "./../../../lib/rpm/core/logger"

class TestLogger < MiniTest::Unit::TestCase
  def setup
    @logger = RPMLogger.new
    @test_msg = "This is a test log message!"
  end

  def test_debug_messages
    log = @logger.debug( @test_msg )
    assert_match "/^[DEBUG] /", log, msg=nil
  end

end
```

I'll be the first to concede there are probably several errors in both files (as I'm still learning) but I'll try to take it one step at a time.

I've searched for related SO articles, and on the web regarding arguments to 'initialize'.  Either they are not directly related, or I misunderstand them. Any assistance appreciated.

Comment: You should probably undo your last edit - Uri posted an answer which now looks to be completely unrelated. If this answer was correct for your first question, accept it and post a second one rather than changing your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error is in this line:

```
require 'log4r', :version=>'=1.1.10'
```

I'm not sure what you tried to do, but `require` receives a single argument. The error `wrong number of arguments` means that you are trying to call a method with an unexpected number of arguments. `(2 for 1)` means you are trying to call a method with one argument with two.

The only method call in `initialize` you are calling with two arguments is `require` - so this is the method in question.

[`require`](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/including_other_files_in_ruby.html) usage is in most cases at the top of ruby files, telling the ruby interpreter which other ruby files should be loaded before loading this file.

`require` does *not* declare gem dependencies, so gem versions are irrelevant here. You can put these in the `Gemfile` file.

Comment: Thanks @UriAgassi, this was useful.  The following articles and discussions confirms your suggestion:
http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/including_other_files_in_ruby.html
https://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/1416
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856243/how-to-require-a-ruby-file-from-another-directory