# getting no such file to load -- xyz (LoadError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have cloned a ruby project from git hub,after cloning I performed  *bundle install.* Now I am trying to run this project but getting require: no such file to load-- xyz (LoadError).
 
  I am running my prj.rb file from bin and it contains

```
 require 'xyz'
```

This xyz.rb  is in the lib folder of my project.

Comment: Hey, http://stackoverflow.com/a/16856993/5596671

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to add `lib` directory to autoload by adding to `config/application.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

Other

```
require "#{Rails.root}/lib/xyz"
```