# How to call ruby class which is in different location in rspec

Tags: rspec

I have a doubt. I came across many website for Rspec tutorial. Most of them create a class and call that respective class in same rb file.

Is there anyway i can call different rb file which is located in different location.

```
class HelloWorld
   def say_hello 
      "Hello World!"
   end   
end

RSpec.describe HelloWorld do
  before do 
    hw = HelloWorld.new 
    @message = hw.say_hello    
  end

  it 'Compare the EXACT word' do                  
    expect(@message).to eql('Hello World!')                                
  end
end
```

The above code is working. If I have `HelloWorld.rb` in another location how do i call it.

Note: I tried require and `require_relative`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856243/how-to-require-a-ruby-file-from-another-directory ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to require a ruby file from another directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856243/how-to-require-a-ruby-file-from-another-directory)

Answer (score 0):

There are two options

1) Maybe puting all your testing files within the same folder and not in the same implementation file might work:
You create a new file for testing and then require all the files you are going to test

2) In that same file, use require for the spec_helper file. Maybe It will solve it.