# Where does require pull ruby files that don't exist on the system?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rake, bundler, rakefile

I followed the steps from [bundler.io](https://bundler.io/guides/creating_gem.html) and am creating my own gem.

Now I'm looking into the `Rakefile`. I see:

```
require "bundler/gem_tasks"
```

but as far as I understand I don't have a `bundler/gem_tasks`. So how is this working? Where is that file expected to be in? How does `require` find files that aren't in its folder?!

Is it just pointing to this file: https://github.com/rubygems/bundler/blob/master/lib/bundler/gem_tasks.rb? Can you just reference single ruby files with just like

```
require someGem/someRubyfile
```

The [ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require) aren't clear about this.

I already looked into [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16856243/how-to-require-a-ruby-file-from-another-directory) and also inspected my `$LOAD_PATH`. It only contains the following:

```
 "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/did_you_mean-1.3.0/lib",
 "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/coderay-1.1.3/lib",
 "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/method_source-1.0.0/lib",
 "/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/pry-0.13.1/lib",
 "/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0",
 "/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin19",
 "/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/universal-darwin19",
 "/Library/Ruby/Site",
 "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.6.0",
 "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin19",
 "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin19",
 "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby",
 "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0",
 "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/x86_64-darwin19",
 "/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin19"]
```

I don't see mention of `bundler`.

Nor I see anything related to `gem_tasks` in `~/.bundle`. Does this mean that upon `rake build` the `bundler/gem_tasks` is going to get downloaded from the internet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rubygems overwrites Ruby's own `Kernel#require` method with [its own method](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/v3.2.2/lib/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb#L22-L34) which loads gems on demand (i.e. adds the gem to the $LOAD_PATH and then requires the requested file).

Thus, when you execute `require 'bundler/gem_tasks'`, what happens is that rubygems searches for a gem containing  `bundler/gem_tasks.rb` in its `require_paths` path (which is specified in the respective gemspec of each gem). If a matching gem is found on your system, its `require_paths` are added to the `$LOAD_PATH` and Ruby's original `require` method is called which will load the requested file.

In any case, neither Ruby nor Rubygems dynamically loads gems from the internet. It will only use gems installed locally to the configured GEM_PATHS. You can find the configured paths which are searched for installed gems by running `gem env` on your command line.

If you start Ruby with the `--disable-gems` command line argument, it will not automatically load rubygems and thus will not add its custom implementation of `Kernel#require`. Here, only files in locations you specifically added to the `$LOAD_PATH` can be required.

Comment: Thanks. FWIW I wrote an answer derived from your answer

Answer (score 0):

This was too big of a comment. It's entirely written off of the accepted answer:

My `require_paths` was just this: `spec.require_paths = ["lib"]` So definitely not there. So when I did `gem env` I got the following:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 3.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.6.3 (2019-04-16 patchlevel 62) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/honey/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/bin/ruby
  - GIT EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/git
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/honey/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-19
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0
     - /Users/honey/.gem/ruby/2.6.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/honey/google-cloud-sdk/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
     - /Library/Apple/usr/bin
```

So the first `GEM PATHS` was: `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0`. Following the breadcrumbs I got to: `/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.2.2/lib/bundler` where I was able to find `gem_tasks.rb`